# I need to do bulk find and replace

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I have file1.txt with these lines

```
abc
def
ghi
```

file2.txt with these lines

```
jkl
mno
pqr    jkl
 
jkl
mno   mno mno
pqr
```

I want to write a script that replaces all occurrences of the string jkl in file2.txt with the first line of file1.txt ... Also, replace all the occurrences of the string mno in file2.txt with the second line of  file1.txt. So after a successful execution of the script, file2.txt should look like this:

file2.txt with these lines

```
abc
def
pqr    abc
 
abc
def   def def
pqr
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Show us your research.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. You should be more explicit. What to do with `ghi`? I mean it will go to substitute `pqr` of the 3rd line or the one of the 6th line?  Which is the field separator (One or more spaces, tabs ...)?  What if you find in a second column a value that never occurred in the first column before? What if you find in a lower line a value already introduced from the 1st file before? Please clear those points to you and [edit] the question to let us know. Do not forget the  Gronostaj's request. `:-)`

Comment: BTW, this sort of thing is easy to get wrong. Make sure you have a good backup before trying anything.